# How to run docker containers from Docker Store in CodeBuild?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-codebuild

I'd like to use docker container from store.docker.com as CodeBuild image.

I can specify my own image but I have to provide repository url. What is the repository url for store.docker.com?

Answer (score 0):

Just set *Custom image type* to *Other* and as *Custom image ID* type the name of the image from store.docker.com.

Eg. for https://store.docker.com/images/node - version with tag `9` type in:

`node:9`